# AS3 FLVPlayback fullscreen mode displays black screen

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flvplayback

I'm trying to use the enterFullScreenDisplayState() function of the Flash AS3 FLVPlayback component, but instead of the video expanding to fill the screen, I just get a completely black screen. I can still hear the video playing, and when I Esc, the video is just playing normally. I'm publishing as an Adobe AIR desktop app (runtime version 3).

I'm a seasoned flash dev, but haven't come across this problem before, and been looking for a solution for a few hours now. Any help would be appreciated. Code for my document class is below. It seems so basic, am I missing something?

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.video.FLVPlayback;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.controls.Button;

public class VidTest extends MovieClip {

    public var vidPlayer:FLVPlayback;
    public var fullscreenBtn:Button;

    public function VidTest() {

        vidPlayer = new FLVPlayback();
        vidPlayer.width = 502;
        vidPlayer.height = 284;
        vidPlayer.source = "airport.f4v";
        addChild(vidPlayer);
        fullscreenBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullscreenHandler);

    }

    public function fullscreenHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        vidPlayer.enterFullScreenDisplayState();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<object> 
... 
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> 
<embed ... allowfullscreen="true" />
```

not sure but this could be the problem.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html